# How can I check if the Data table contains the value I want and possibly click on the link?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using web driver and need to check whether the Data table contains the value I want and possibly click on the link?
I guess it should work with xpath?

For example:
I have web application that has datatable with 3 columns, where

```
<div id="studyResultsId">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td><a href="/portal/study/studyAction!view.action?studyId=STUDY0000222">Using Automation</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/portal/study/studyAction!view.action?studyId=STUDY0000281">Using Design</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/portal/study/studyAction!view.action?studyId=STUDY0000272">Using Development</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

---

I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
    String abc = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='studyResultsId']/div/table/tbody/tr/td")).getText();

    //Retrieving the data from the Td of table in to a string
    if(abc.contains("Automation")) {
        System.out.println("contains Automation");
    } else {
        System.out.println("does not contains Automation");
    }
}
```

Comment: this didnot work fo me:

Answer (score 2):

As per your html, I would like to talk about your xpath first,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='studyResultsId']/div/table/tbody/tr/td")).getText();
```

The String 'foo' in following line is what you are able to get by your xpath above.

```
<div id="studyResultsId'><div><table><tbody><tr><td>foo</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>
```

Back to your html. Basically when you were searching by id='studyResultsId' you had already access the first div tag. So don't need the second '/div' again. Then you tried to locate 'td', yeah in current situation you had get the first 'td' element. But as you can see, all of the tag **td** have no **text**. It's tag a who has text. So you need to archive tag a and traverse it. Following code is my suggestion

```
//Initilize your webdriver first
List<WebElement> wl = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='studyResultsId']//a"));

        for(int i=0; i<wl.size(); i++) {
            WebElement current = wl.get(i);

            if(current.getText().contains("Automation")) {
                System.out.println("Current tag '" + current.getText() + "' has text Automation");
            }  else {
                System.out.println("Current tag '" + current.getText() + "' has no text Automation");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

As J.Lyu and sideshowbarker have already offered concise suggestions for your XPath expression I'll decline to offer another, however for brevity's sake here is how I would locate the required link WebElement(s) using other locators:

First I would start by locating the table WebElement using its [id attribute](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-id):

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("studyResultsId"));
```

There are two approaches you could now take to locate the required link(s):

1. [By Partial Link Text](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-partial-link-text) -

   ```
   // This will return all link WebElements within the table
   // that have partial matching visible text.

   List<WebElement> matchingLinks = table.findElements(By.partialLinkText("Automation"));
   ```
2. [By Tag Name](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-tag-name) -

   ```
   // This will return all link WebElements within the table

   List<WebElement> tableLinks = table.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
   ```

   To identify which of these link elements contain the text 'Automation', you can use a standard Java expression like so:

   ```
   List<WebElement> matchingLinks = new ArrayList<>();

   for (WebElement link : tableLinks) {
      if (link.contains("Automation")) {
         matchingLinks.add(link);
      }
   }
   ```

You can then use either `matchingLinks` list of WebElements as required.